# Should I initialize variables on declaration, init block, constructor or lateinit?

Tags: kotlin

I was wondering whats the difference between the 4 ways of initializing a variable (that I know of) in kotlin and which one would be the most accepted one.

First, initialize it on declaration:

```
class MyClass {
   var textString: String = "Hello world"
}
```

Second, initialize it on the init block:

```
class MyClass {
   var textString: String

   init {
      textString = "Hello world"
   }
}
```

Third, use a constructor:

```
class MyClass {
    var textString : String

    constructor() {
        this.textString = "Hello world"
    }
}
```

Fourth, lateinit:

```
class MyClass {
    lateinit var textString : String

    fun initializeVariable() { //Assume this is called by something
        this.textString = "Hello world"
    }
}
```

I am mostly looking for the difference on compile time and the overall "good practice". I am aware of some "tricks" you can use, like using the init block to initialize some variables that are always the same regardless of the constructor used, but would that be the appropiate way of doing it?

Comment: There are multiple ways as there are multiple needs, therefore there's no one-fits-all aproach so I am voting to close this question as opinion based.

Comment: "I was wondering whats the difference between the 4 ways of initializing a variable" I don't think thats opinion based. The "whats the most optimal solution" I agree sounds opinion based but It is due to poor wording on my part. I meant where would I want to use each one and why that one would be better than the others.

Comment: If you're setting a field to a known constant the best way is to just option 1. Use constructor/init if you need to do somethng the constructor arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the technical standpoint, there's no much difference, at least in terms of simple properties like in the example - the property gets initialised anyway.

The `lateinit` modifier is a little exception here - it allows for a delayed initialization: it's like saying "I cannot set a meaningful value now, but I'm sure that it will be set before the first use". It is useful in Kotlin - Spring Framework integration, when one, for some reason doesn't want/cannot use constructor injection, and allows for property injection.

```
 @Autowired lateinit var foo: Foo
```

or  when using Spring's `@Value` annotation

```
 @Value("\#{props.foo}") lateinit var foo: String
```

There's a difference, though, from the reader / maintainer point of view, and when you need some extra functionality, say precondition validation. As a rule of thumb initialise your properties as early as possible: the preferred way is in the primary constructor:

```
class Foo(var bar: String = "default value")
```

The reader of your code, maybe future you, won't have to jump trough the code to understand where does the "default value" come from - it's right in the constructor!

Additionally, client code, can easily change the value when constructing the object, or leave it default

```
// set new value
val foo: Foo = Foo(bar = "specific value other than default")

// leave the default
val defaultFoo: Foo = Foo()
```

Having the property initialised in class body, forces the client code to firstly create an instance with a default, and only then override.

```
val foo = Foo()
foo.bar = "not so default"
```

Additionally, if there're some preconditions which you like to check, it's easier to do this when setting the values in the primary constructor. E.g. the foo String property cannot be blank:

```
class Foo(var bar: String = "default") {
    init {
        require(bar.isNotBlank()) { "Bar cannot be blank" }
   }
}
```

Where it's possible I'd go with constructor initialization.

Also, if you are willing to spend a few dollars on a book on good practices and patterns in Kotlin, I highly recommend Marin Moskała's *Effective Kotlin* https://leanpub.com/effectivekotlin

Comment: When you say`lateinit` was useful in the early days of Kotlin, are you implying that is no longer useful?

Comment: @Tenfour04 it's still useful for property injection or when you cannot initialize something during constructor - for example in android you wait for platform call to `onCreate` since this is the first point where you can reference application resources.

Comment: @Pawel That’s what I was getting at.

Comment: I've clarified the answer, as @Pawel mentioned, this is still useful when using Dependecy Injection via properties, and not constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`lateinit` is irrelevant because it doesn't initialize anything.

Initialization on the same line is only for simple properties. You can use closures and then invoke them, like so `val i = { // complex code }()`, but it's ugly.

For a detail discussion of constructor vs `init` block, see [this](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/constructor-initialization-vs-init-block-in-kotlin/2338). The simplest way to understand the initialization order is to create a class with a primary, secondary and an `init` block, and then either use `println` or simply a debugger to follow the execution.